# Hat Placement Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

When dragging hats around on my profile picture, the hat is limited to the bounds of the picture. However, with a very small hat, dragging out of bounds is possible at the corners. Simply pull your mouse far enough from the profile and move the hat back and forth until it jumps out to the mouse pointer's location. Like my current hat right now.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that a "bug". What problems does it cause?

Comment: @JonEricson It seems to be unintended behaviour, that's why I called it a bug. The hat is limited to the profile, except in this instance. It makes sense; now the hat could block things (slightly, but it doesn't). Other things that are happening: my hat sometimes disappears for a split second, but I don't know if that would normally happen.

Comment: @JonEricson Yeah this is definitely a bug, the hat should never completely leave the area of the avatar.

Comment: Simply go to [this URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/nocaptcha) then to see the captcha at work, and even so, at least give useful summary e.g. "testing Captcha"

Comment: It does now... Geoff only said that in comment. Sorry too, one of the few things that are really irritating me is users who try to harvest rep by illegal bumping, glad to see you're not one of them after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very nice catch.

One of the rules that restrict the placement of the hats is that at least 40% of the hat's area must overlap with the avatar. But there was a bug (both in the JavaScript and on the server) in the code that implements this rule: When calculating the overlapping rectangle, its width and height weren't capped at zero. In the case you found, the width and the height of the rectangle are both negative, and thus their product was positive again, making it possible for the calculated overlapping area to be above the 40% threshold even though there wasn't actually any overlap at all.

This is fixed now. I've let you (and anyone else who exploited this) keep your current hat position, but once you change anything about your hat, you won't be able to keep it. So it's up to you whether you want to keep your hat as is, as a proof of finding this bug, or if that eventually gets old :)

Comment: Well done! ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้